# Memory Consumption with Encryption, AES

Tags: encryption, aes

I just wonder if could any one know if the Memory consumed by AES for encrypting a text file will be equal to the  memory consumed to decrypt the same file.

Thanks.

Comment: Very likely *yes*, but without an actual implementation, this is not possible to answer.

Comment: I have written my code to calculate the memory consumption for AES encryption and decryption, and what I got that there is no big different, But will the bigger file size consumes more memory or not. @Artjom B. Thanks a million

Comment: @SehamHAmmad The AES algorithm itself has a rather small state, depending on the implementation, maybe a KB or so for fast implementations. The rest is up to how it is used, most modes of operation only need to cache a block at maximum, but naive implementations may just buffer everything.

Comment: if you are so concerned about memory consumption (which is usually not a concern for AES), I assume you target a rather small system (little memory, relatively weak cpu). you maybe should rather be concerned about cpu cycle consumption and speed then, esp. if there is no hw acceleration for aes on that platform and the amount of data you want to encrypt is not just a little...

Answer (score 1):

The AES algorithm itself has a rather small state which - depending on the implementation - is only a KB or so for fast implementations (+ some static tables). The rest is up to how AES is used, most modes of operation - such as CBC - only need to cache a block at maximum. Naïve implementations may just buffer everything.

If you use CTR mode of operation then a key stream is generated which is used both for encryption and decryption. Encryption/decryption is *exactly the same operation*. In that case it's of course logical that the same amount of memory is used for encryption and decryption.

In principle the memory consumed for CTR could be just the internal state of the cipher implementation, a single block for the encrypted counter and a single bit for the input / output. In general though you want to buffer larger amounts of plain/ciphertext for efficiency reasons though.